# SQL WHERE clause not filtering out specified value using !=/<>

Tags: mysql, sql

Writing a query based on an assignment. The question asks: "list all non-USA based locations that have beginner or intermediate level activities".

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Location.LCountry, Activity.ALevel
FROM Location, Activity
WHERE LCountry != 'USA'
AND ALevel = 'Beginner' OR ALEVEL' = 'Intermediate';
```

When I run this query, I still get a list that includes values with the USA. When I do not include the `OR ALevel = 'Intermediate"` clause, it prints out the correct query.

Comment: You have missing/extra single quotes in several places.  Fix those typos and the query should at least run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OR condition` in parenthesis

```
SELECT DISTINCT Location.LCountry, Activity.ALevel
FROM Location inner join Activity on Location.LCountry=Activity.Country
WHERE LCountry != 'USA'
AND (ALevel = 'Beginner' OR ALEVEL = 'Intermediate');
```

OR you can use IN Operator like below

```
SELECT DISTINCT Location.LCountry, Activity.ALevel
FROM Location inner join Activity on Location.LCountry=Activity.Country
WHERE LCountry != 'USA'
AND ALevel in( 'Beginner' , 'Intermediate');
```

Comment: That did work. Thank you. What is the difference in terms of why including parenthesis works compared to not using parenthesis?

Comment: The queries you suggest are still missing a proper join condition.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What does the join condition do? I did not include that, but my query ran as desired

Comment: @jadendej you are using a implicit join between two tables. It's better to use explicit join between tables with proper joining key - there is must be some relation belong between your two tables

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an ANSI-92 type JOIN and proper quotation as :

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.LCountry, a.ALevel
  FROM Location l
  LEFT JOIN Activity a
    ON ( l.location = a.location )
 WHERE l.LCountry != 'USA'
   AND ( a.ALevel = 'Beginner' OR a.ALEVEL = 'Intermediate');
```

by the way, aliasing makes a query more handsome to read.

alternatively use grouping to get distinct results as :

```
SELECT l.LCountry, a.ALevel
  FROM Location l
  LEFT JOIN Activity a
     ON ( l.location = a.location )
 WHERE l.LCountry != 'USA'
   AND ( a.ALevel = 'Beginner' OR a.ALEVEL = 'Intermediate')
 GROUP BY l.LCountry, a.ALevel;
```

Comment: The OP also need to add `()` for `OR`

Comment: @AbdulRasheed yes, in a rush I didn't realize thanks akh.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes in different places are not placed accordingly or misplaced.

So try the below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Location.LCountry, Activity.ALevel
FROM Location, Activity
WHERE Location.LCountry <> 'USA'
AND Activity.ALevel IN ('Beginner','Intermediate')
```

Comment: I thought <> and != are the same thing. Using <> instead of != resulted in the same undesired query

Answer (score 0):

Use the updated query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Location.LCountry, Activity.ALevel
FROM Location, Activity
WHERE LCountry != 'USA'
AND (ALevel = 'Beginner' OR ALEVEL' = 'Intermediate');
```